# Как отобразить изображение в теги IMG средствами PHP с заблокированного сайта?

Tags: php, html

Такая задача которую не знаю как решить.

Есть картинка которая находится на сайте который мой провайдер заблокировал.

Мой сайт находится в другой стране и от туда к заблокированному сайту есть доступ, я использую api этого заблокированного сайта без проблем. Но когда питаюсь с заблокированного сайта Вывести картинку на своем сайте она не грузится.

Подскажите пожалуйста, в какую сторону копать?

----------**Спустя X времени поиска сделал так** -----

```
$uri = $avatar;
$imageget = file_get_contents ($users_get[$user_id]["avatar"]);
$image = ImageCreateFromString($imageget);
ob_start();
imagepng($image);
$png = ob_get_clean();
$uri = "data:image/jpg;base64," . base64_encode($png);
echo "<img src=" . $uri . " />";
```

У меня этот код выполняется в цикле, в итоге никоторые картинки не отображаются, в HTML такое `src="data:image/jpg;base64,"`

В чем проблема не знаю :(

Comment: копать в сторону ркн. Или скачать себе картинки на сервер и отдавать их.

Comment: Есть возможность править конфиг Nginx, и есть ли он вообще? Могу набросать конфиг, который будет иметь кеш картинок на диске + скачивать по требованию. Картинки будут иметь адреса http://ваш-сайт/proxy-images/?http://заблокированный-сайт/image.jpg Это решение будет намного лучше онлайн-скачивания. И no code решение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете сделать отдельный php файл, который будет тянуть для вас картинки с заблокированного сайта, и я бы туда еще кеширование добавил, а путь к картинкам задавайте в get-параметре. Например, создаем get_image.php и кладем в корне сайта:

```php
<?php
if($path = filter_input(INPUT_GET,'image-path')){
    // тут сделать  логику по определению типа картики и выдаче нужного заголовка
    header('Content-Type: image/png'); 
    echo file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/'.$path);
}
```

Теперь на самой странице, например в index.php, задаем урл картинки следующим образом:

```php
<html>
...
<img src="/get_image.php?<?= http_build_query([
    'image-path' => 'images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_dark_color_272x92dp.png'
]) ?>">
...
</html>
```

В результате домен не меняется и картинки не блокируются.
Еще можно сделать красивый урл для картинок, если в .htaccess поколдовать

Comment: Чет ничего у меня не получается :(
Я хочу получить картинку например с этого сайта https://site.ru/images/sdfjsidjfdsi.jpg и вывести ее у себя на сайте.

Comment: Отредактировал ответ, сделал рабочий пример для изображения с сайта www.google.com